# Again - can't change global variable in C

Tags: c, global-variables

I'm newbie to C, and this question could be asked for 100 times, but I can't find the same case.
Here's the code:

```
int r;
void set_idt() {
    r = 0x88;
    if(r == 0){
        kprint_hex_byte(0xff);
    }
}
```

It's strange, but I can't modify the global variable and **kprint_hex_byte** gets executed. When I try to pick **&r** inside **set_idt()** I get the valid address, but assignment of the variable doesn't work!

**UPDATE**

I decided to provide a minimal example
Here's the minified code:

```
int r = 0x34def;

void main(){
    r = 0x33;

    char d = 0;
    if(r == 0){
        d = 1;
    }
    else{
        d = 2;
    }
}
```

I try to  compile it and disassemble it using the following commands:

```
gcc -ffreestanding -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-pie -m32 -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
ld -o kernel.bin -m elf_i386 --oformat binary kernel.o
ndisasm -b 32 kernel.bin > kernel.dis
```

So as a result of this operations I don't have any hint that any variable **r** or address space is initialized as 0x34def.
Here's the .dis code:

```
00000000  55                push ebp
00000001  89E5              mov ebp,esp
00000003  83EC10            sub esp,byte +0x10
00000006  C7052C9004083300  mov dword [dword 0x804902c],0x33
         -0000
00000010  C645FF00          mov byte [ebp-0x1],0x0
00000014  A12C900408        mov eax,[0x804902c]
00000019  85C0              test eax,eax
0000001B  7506              jnz 0x23
0000001D  C645FF01          mov byte [ebp-0x1],0x1
00000021  EB04              jmp short 0x27
00000023  C645FF02          mov byte [ebp-0x1],0x2
00000027  90                nop
00000028  C9                leave
00000029  C3                ret
```

PS
In the original example when I tried to disassemble it, I also had some assembler instructions dealing with expected memory address and commands **test** and **jnz** were presented the exact same way, but it didn't work as expected

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the code you've shown.

Comment: There's not enough here to see what you might be doing wrong.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: How do you call `set_idt` and how do you know that `kprint_hex_byte` is called in `set_idt`? Please show a [mre].

Comment: I call it inside my kernel.c main{} and I know that kprint_hex_byte works because it outputs the 0xff onto VGA memory and I can see it.

Comment: @dbush, the reproducible example is quite long and consists of many .asm and .c files and requires running in QEMU, so it's hard to attach it

Comment: How much code do you need to support this example use of `kprint_hex_byte()`? Please get used to setting up little test files to check out small things you do. If it works as it should then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: The global variable `r` is at address 0x804902c. `main` is not responsible for initializing `r` to 0x34def. That initialization should happen before `main` is called. But `main` does attempt to write 0x33 to address 0x804902c. If that's not working, then it's either because your memory map is incorrect, or because you didn't set up that memory area correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @user3386109. The memory map is indeed incorrect because it's a very minified example - just one file. I'll try to look closely to my cross-compiler and build processes to solve the original problem